# how to get googleappid for firebase firestore config?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am trying to create a flutter application which connects to firestore to store and retrieve data. from the flutter cloud_firestore plugin docs, i can see that i need some values to configure it.

```
final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'test',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
           googleAppID: '1:79601577497:ios:5f2bcc6ba8cecddd',
           gcmSenderID: '79601577497',
           apiKey: 'AIzaSyArgmRGfB5kiQT6CunAOmKRVKEsxKmy6YI-G72PVU',
           projectID: 'flutter-firestore',
        ),
    );
```

I know how to fetch the gcmSenderID, apiKey and projectID, but i am not able to understand how to get the googleAppID.

Please advice
  final Firestore firestore = new Firestore(app: app);

Comment: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en

Comment: thanks, i didn't notice the id in clients list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @martin-zeitler suggested, the id is availabile in the downloaded google-services.json file. 
thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There are a few IDs listed in this file.   Would have been nice to know which particular one maps to googleAppID.

Comment: look for the value in this key 

"client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id":

Answer (score 0):

Login to firebase --> cog wheel next to Project Overview --> Project settings --> scroll down to "Your apps" (add one if missing) --> will show "SDK setup and configuration"

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can get `gcmsenderId` from [this link](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/abs-luncher/settings/cloudmessaging/)

[image]